# Linking python script with HTML input page

Tags: python, html

Is there a way for me to enter data (a name for example) into an HTML input box and then use that name in a python script that returns results to the HTML page? The W3 website says the following:

" defines a button for submitting form data to a form-handler.
The form-handler is typically a server page with a script for processing input data.
The form-handler is specified in the form's action attribute:'

Can the server side form-handler be a python code?

Comment: Look into Flask or Django

Comment: This question is really too broad for stackoverflow but, yes, Flask and Django are the two most established Python-fro-the-web frameworks. Check out https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world